# I can t write in pascal expression

Tags: pascal

I try ti write this expression in PascaL (sin(x*g))^3 - cos(g^2) but i have always mistake
My code here:

```
 z:=exp(ln(sin(x*g))*3)-cos(exp(ln(g)*2));
 Writeln('z=',z);
```

z,x,g is real

Comment: What is your "mistake"? Unexpected result? Code does not compile?

Comment: Why are you taking the logarithm of x*g and g?

Comment: Read up on the correct use of that `exp` function. Hint: it does not want a `*`.

Comment: And don't forget most Pascal implentations use sin and cos in RAD, not degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has three potential problems.

Firstly, if there is any chance of the sin function returning a negative value (or if g is negative), the log function will fail with an error.

Secondly, Sqr(g), or even g*g, is far more efficient, and is clearer, than exp(ln(g)*2).

Thirdly, it is clearer to understand, probably more efficient, and may be numerically more accurate to use the Power function rather than your exp/ln method.

So I would replace your code with something like the following:

```
 Temp := Sin(x*g);
 z := Sign(Temp)*Power(Abs(Temp),3) - cos(Sqr(g));
```

Comment: Any legitimate reason for the down-vote (if not the missing Abs())?